# CouchDB view default options in design document not working

Tags: couchdb

The problem is simple: I have written `map` functions in a design document of a CouchDB database, which emits something `{"_id":doc._id}`. Together with `include_docs=true` query option, I will get the desired results with the linked documents. Because the `map` functions are designed to work with `include_docs=true`, I put this option in the design document and make it default:

```
{...
    "options":{"include_docs":true}
...}
```

However, when I query the view, the results are still those without the linked documents, and I need to specify the option explicitly in the query. I also tried to pu other query option (e.g. `limit=200`) into the design document, they did not work either.

I am using CouchDB 1.5, and cannot find any discussion, issue or bug regarding this. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advanced!

**Edit: I have reported the issue in Apache, and I am told that the statement about this was removed.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `_design/ddoc/options` cannot do that.

According to [couchdb's docs](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#view-options), a design doc's `options` object properties only affect view *indexing*, not view *querying*. (The only two settings being `local_seq` and `include_design`).

---

### `_design/ddoc/rewrites` can!

If you want to set query options server side, you can do so by specifying a `rewrites` array in your design document.

Let's say you want to expose a query to `_view/myview` that has `include_docs` set to `true`, you add the following `rewrites` array to your design document:

```
{ "_id": "_design/myddoc"
, "views": { "myview": { "map": "function(doc) { ... }" } }
, "rewrites":
  [ { "from": "allmyviews/myview"
    , "to": "_view/myview"
    , "query": 
      { "include_docs": "true"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, when you request `http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/myddoc/_rewrite/allmyviews/myview` *without* the `include_docs` parameter, couchdb will respond as if you had included it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using rewrite I did not try yet, but I will have a look. However, according to the [the docs (exactly your link)](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#view-options), it says **In additional to these options, you may specify any other with their default value. E.g. having option "include_docs": true will automatically includes document body for view results response. You still may override such by explicitly defining same query parameter name with other value.**. Your first opinion doesn't agree with this! How is this to be understood?

Comment: Hmm, you are right. (I originally referenced the [couchdb wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) -- which says nothing about default query options -- but decided to change the link to rtd.org for nicer looks). There is a [jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1188) concerning default view options, but it's still unresolved. Going through couchdb's git history, I do see the change in the docs, but could not find anything related in the code base. You might need to open your own ticket in jira to examine this further.

Comment: Thanks! I also found the jira ticket before, but I don't think it is the same issue as the one I have. It's weird that no one has encountered such an issue before while it should be quite a nice feature. I think I will post an issue or a bug to CouchDB.

Comment: Hi @skiqh, I tried your advise to use rewrite. However it is still not working, I got `{"error":"rewrite_error","reason":"Invalid path."}`. I defined the rewrite rule as the following: `[
   {
       "to": "/_view/film_actor",
       "from": "/actors_in_film",
       "query": {
           "include_docs": true
       }
   }
]`, and I queried `localhost/database/_design/basic/_rewrite/actors_in_film` (where `basic` is the design doc. I read also the docs about rewrite, the examples are pretty messy, except the very basic rule, the others with variables are very messed up!

Comment: Trying to replicate your problem, I just realized that you have to provide the query parameters as strings (i.e. `"include_docs": "true"`, not `"include_docs": true`) -- edited my answer to reflect this. Besides that, it's working for me. On the other hand, this would have produced an `unknown_error/badarg` error, which you do not get, abviously. What does your log say when you query that rewrite endpoint? Does the view itself (without the rewrite in between) return a valid response?

Comment: This is strange, I did like you said, changed `true` to `"true"`, but still not working. I also tried to remove the first slash in the `"to"` and `"from"` fields (like exactly in your post), still not luck. When querying the view itself, it is working as expected. And the log said `404`, from the browser the message is still the `Invalid path`

Comment: According to the [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=couchdb.git;a=blob;f=src/couchdb/couch_httpd_rewrite.erl;h=4354215f082f41d83c9fbcad366c56a9c187f455;hb=d43f69d90740d5a230b0054fa32b6843b33691bc) the `invalid path` error also gets thrown when the design doc does not have a property called `rewrites` (*plural*). Maybe you mistyped it (e.g. `rewrite`) ?

Comment: After plenty of retries I finally made it work! One possible reason was indeed the word `rewrites` was wrong, only from the source view of the design document I could see that there was a space before! I removed the space and it worked. Thank you all your help along this issue!

Comment: Beware that rewrite rules are deprecated since 3.0, and will be removed in 4.0.